# Setting a lightning:card title bold

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've been trying to set a `lightning:card`'s title bold, but I can't seem to be able to. So far I've tried using the `slds-text-heading_small`, putting `<b>` tags in the title and a few other things, but it doesn't work.

How do you get the look and feel of the standard components where the title is bold?

This is my component:

```
<aura:component description="WatchlistIndicator"></aura:component>
    <lightning:card class="slds-text-heading_small" title="Watchlist (0)" iconName="utility:broadcast">
      <aura:set attribute="actions">
          <lightning:buttonMenu iconSize="x-small">
              <lightning:menuItem label="Open Watchlist app" value="Open" />
              <lightning:menuItem label="Add to Watchlist app" value="Add" />
          </lightning:buttonMenu>
      </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
  </aura:component>
```

But it looks like this:

[image: Picture]

PS: as a bonus, do you know why the menu items appear on the right and not on the left as standard ones usually do?

Comment: I don't know why the code isn't rendering... It's written in the question. Any mod?

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: Have you tried to set the `font-weight: bold;` in the class attribute?

Comment: @RCS yup, I tried that too. It doesn't work :-(

Comment: I think the CSS property is been overridden

Comment: @RCS and how could I fix that? I've tried `<lightning:card class="font-weight: bold !important;" title="Watchlist (0)">` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: try using `font-weight: bold !important;` that means this will the 1st priority and it will not be overridden

Comment: BTW, you cannot write a style inside a class attribute, you need to put define a class and add styles in `style` component. And [`!important` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/1023542).

Comment: Answer the bonus - it is an attribute of the `lightning:buttonMenu` component - you should add `menuAlignment` attribute:  `<lightning:buttonMenu iconSize="x-small" menuAlignment="left">`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [`lightning:card`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card), title has type as `object`.  And the section Usage Considerations states:

> The title and footer attributes are of type Object, which means that you can pass in values of String or Component[] types among some others.

Note: Use `menuAlignment` attribute on `lightning:buttonMenu` component to align your dropdown button menu.

Based on this knowledge and example from documentation, we can try below code:

```
<aura:component description="WatchlistIndicator">

    <aura:attribute name="headerTitle" type="Aura.Component[]">
        <h2>
            <b>Watchlist (0)</b>
        </h2>
    </aura:attribute>

    <lightning:card class="slds-text-heading_small" 
        title="{!v.headerTitle}" iconName="utility:broadcast">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:buttonMenu iconSize="x-small" menuAlignment="right">
                <lightning:menuItem label="Open Watchlist app" value="Open" />
                <lightning:menuItem label="Add to Watchlist app" value="Add" />
            </lightning:buttonMenu>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

Which would give the output as:

[image: ![output]

Comment: Cheerio Rahul! :)

Answer (score 2):

> How do you get the look and feel of the standard [card] components
>   where the title is bold?

The [SLDS standard for a card](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/) is not very clear about how and why card titles seem to be bolded.  If you look at the output in a browser, you will see that the card title's font weight is affected by the class `slds-card__header-link`.

Accordingly:

- If a card title **is** a link, it should have a heavier font weight (a.k.a. it should be bolded).
- If a card title is **not** a link, then it should have a normal font weight.

As the currently accepted [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/214208/31260) indicates, the appropriate way to get that link into a card title is to *not* just type it into the card element's `title` attribute.  Instead:

- With an old-style Aura Lightning component, [use an aura attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/documentation).
- With a Lightning Web Component, [use a slot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/documentation), for example, a "div" with an "a" within it, like this:

  ```
  <div slot="title">
      <a class="slds-card__header-link" href="...">My card title</a>
  </div>
  ```

Incidentally, you do not need to add the `slds-card__header` class to the `div` because that is done for you because you're setting the `div` attribute `slot="title"`.

Comment: Worked for LWC, Thanks